# How to access member with same name in the inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a question about how to access the member with the same name with inheritance. For example,

```
class Base { 

public:
int i;  

};
class Derived1 : public Base {

    public:
    int i;

    // how to access the i in the base class here?
};

int main() {

  Derived1 d;
  cout<<d.i;                          //which is it is?

  //how to access the different i here? 

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`d.i` in your example refers to the `i` in the derived class.

You can refer to the base class `i` by qualifying it with the base class name:

```
d.Base::i
```

In general, it's a bad idea to have derived classes with members having the same name as members in base classes.

Comment: +1 for answering the question as asked and pointing out that it's generally not a good idea to do so.